# How to safely exit a Swing application

Tags: java, swing

I have a program that processes some files.  From time to time, I need to stop it in the middle of processing, but am having difficulty with how to accomplish that.  I have seen several possibilities, but I'm not sure which to pursue.  Is it multithreading, like in a game?  I found some information on cancelling, but it seems like it only applies while data is being inputted?  I'm including the code for my gui below as maybe I just did something wrong?

To be clear, the goal is to stop the program no matter where it is in processing...

```
private JRadioButton blockButton, unblockButton;
private JButton btnCancel;
private ButtonGroup group;
private JLabel text;
private JButton enter;

public Gui(){
    super("Download CORS files");
    setLayout(null);

    text = new JLabel("Would you like to download data in a block of days or intermittently over time?");
    add(text);

    blockButton = new JRadioButton("Block of Days", true);
    unblockButton = new JRadioButton("Intermittent Days", false);
    btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel run");
    add(blockButton);
    add(unblockButton);
    add(btnCancel);

    group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(blockButton);
    group.add(unblockButton);

    // Get the size of the screen
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    // Determine the new location of the window
    int w = this.getSize().width;
    int h = this.getSize().height;
    int x = ((dim.width-w)/2)-200;
    int y = ((dim.height-h)/2)-200;
    // Move the window
    this.setLocation(x, y);

    enter = new JButton("Enter");
    enter.addActionListener(this);
    add(enter);

    text.setBounds(5,5,700,25);
    blockButton.setBounds(5, 25, 300, 25);
    unblockButton.setBounds(5,50, 300, 25);
    enter.setBounds(75,100,100,20);
    btnCancel.setBounds(300,100,100,20);

    btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }});
```

Comment: Call `System.exit(1);`. That will stop it.

Comment: If you're trying to terminate an option from a Swing window, that's not thread-safe. You'll need to set up a task instead to allow for Swing's functionality to work.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to exit a program when I want an exception to be thrown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171265/best-way-to-exit-a-program-when-i-want-an-exception-to-be-thrown)

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Del, Start Task Manager, select your program, and select "cancel".

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I've been using the task manager to kill it, but I figure there should be a way programatically to handle it.

Comment: So basically, you want to show a GUI to start the program, and when it is running, you want to be able to press a "stop" button to abort the process.  Correct?  When you abort, do you want to exit the program as well, or is it just a task in your program that you want to stop?

Comment: And to be clear, the program ends just fine when it reaches conclusion.  I am looking for a way to programatically interrupt it working and close the program.

Comment: @FlorianF Either would work for my purposes, but the best answer would be a hard, cold stop to the entire program.

Comment: If you've got a GUI you should be able to add a "Quit" button.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to stop processing, depending on the situation

1. Stop processing I/O: If you need to break out of an I/O process, IMO the best way to do this is to close the Stream(s), especially for Reader threads. You may get an IOException thrown, but this is what Exceptions are for
2. Intense computation/processing: If you want to stop an intense processing loop, you should call Thread.interrupt() on the processing Thread. If you have written the processing code, you can check on Thread.interrupted() status somewhere in your loop/code. On the other hand, if you are using 3rd party code, this may or may not work

Comment: So, would the Thread.interrupt() work in the form of a button I could press, which would stop the program from processing and shut down? I'm not so worried about I/O, but really from stopping the processing without the task manager.  Maybe that's a perfectly acceptable method, but it feels wrong to rely on that exclusively.

Comment: Yes, you could implement this with an action of a button click

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence of your comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: It refers to using the task manager to stop the program.  Is it ok to just rely on the task manager? My gut tells me no, but that was the first thing people answered above.  I dont want to overly complicate things if it is not necessary.

Comment: I guess you could use the Task Manager if you are sure you're not locking system resources (like sockets)